# Swift avoiding retainment cycles with child viewControllers and singleton usage

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, architecture, protocols, mvp

I've been using singletons far too much and its resulted in memory leaks and some issues managing states. I am trying to understand to proper alternatives to using singletons and general dependency injection, ie protocols.

The example I'm trying to work with is MainViewController has a pager that displays ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB respectively. MainViewController has selector that determines the contentType of ViewControllerA/ViewControllerB respectively. Basically when a different contentType is selected I need to reload the data for the displayed child ViewController. I'm trying to figure out how to properly call the reloadData with the selected ContentType in the children viewController. If I create instances of the class wide children viewControllers, and do something like:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

...

    @objc func contentSelectorTapped() {
         ...
         reloadDisplayChild(prodTypeForIndex(i))
    }

    func reloadDisplayedChild(_ prodType: ProductType) {
        switch currentPage {
            case .pageA
                pageA.reloadData(prodType)
            case .pageB
                pageB.reloadData(prodType)
        }
    }

}

...

class PageAViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    func reloadData(_ prodType: ProductType) {
        ...
        //Normally I would call a datalayer singleton I created but I am trying to move away from this approach
    }
}
```

I worry that I will be creating a retainment cycle and I feel like there will be high amount of overhead. And if this is ok how should I be declaring my instances of the child viewControllers so that they do not create a retainment cycle?

```
lazy var pageAVC: UIPageAViewController = {
    let page = UIPageAVC()
    page.delegate = self
...
    return page
}()
```

I feel like conceptually I understand how to avoid retainment cycles but I'm struggling to actually implement it and maintain some architectural structure (in my case MVP).

Comment: I don't see that you have any retain cycles here. `MainVC` holds a reference to `pageA` and to `pageB`. But `pageA` and `pageB` don't hold any strong reference to `MainVC`. If you had a reference to `MainVC` in `pageA` for example, then you would have a reference cycle, and the proper way to avoid that would be to make `pageA` reference weak in MainVC: `private weak var pageA: PageAViewController?`

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. So just a clarification I should set my delegate for pageA  to MainVC elsewhere since I can't use self inside without "lazy" and if I declare the variable "weak" I can't declare it "lazy" as well.

Comment: Oh, I missed the `page.delegate` part. You do have a retain cycle then! In this case, you should declare `delegate` in `UIPageAViewController ` as weak. Doing so you'll be able to still have your `pageAVC` declared as a lazy var and you'll break the retain cycle.

Comment: Btw, if those variables are not going to be accessed elsewhere, I suggest to inject your delegate on`UIPageAViewController `'s initializer: `init(delegate: SomeProtocol) { self.delegate = delegate) ... }`. That way you can make `private weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?`, and in `MainVC`: `private lazy var pageAVC = UIPageAViewController(delegate: self)`